# How to clip an element fron another one in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mask, clip

I want to create a shape which kinda looks like a match. The *head* is an `Ellipse` with a solid `Stroke` and a somewhat transparent `Fill`. The *stick* is a border with a solid `BorderBrush` and a somewhat transparent `Background`.

I can combine those two elements and it actually looks fine. The issue is, that the `Fill` of the `Ellipse` is transparent so you can see the beginning of the border (red part in the image).

Now my question is: How can I clip this part of my `Border`?

- [Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASq7k.png)
- [Actual WPF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoG9P.png)

maybe someone can edit this post so the images can be inline

---

Example Code

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Fill="#33000000"
             Stroke="#FF000000"
             StrokeThickness="2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Width="15" Height="15" />

    <Border Height="9" Margin="10 0 0 3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            BorderThickness="0 2"
            BorderBrush="#FF000000"
            Background="#33000000" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You will need to construct the non-regular area using geometry operations, and create a geometry shape from that, rather than attempting to combine higher-level shape objects directly. See marked duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho hm okay. How do I create a `BorderThicknes="0 2"` equivalent though? `Path.StrokeThickness` is just a `double`

Comment: Obviously, you will need to construct the "border" part of your shape using multiple paths so that you can specify the parts the way you need.